# I get an "undefined is not a function" error when trying to fetch data in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-context

I keep getting an undefined is not a function error. It works fine on web but not on the Android simulator, nor on the Expo Go apps for iOS and Android

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

const TOKEN_KEY = "fk_token";
export const API_URL = "http://myapi/api";

const AuthContext = createContext();

export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
};

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [authState, setAuthState] = useState({
    token: null,
    authenticated: null,
  });

  axios.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] =
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadToken = async () => {
      try {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY);
        if (token) {
          axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;

          setAuthState({
            token: token,
            authenticated: true,
          });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    loadToken();
  }, []);

  const register = async (email, password, firstname, lastname) => {
    const formData = {
      firstname: firstname,
      lastname: lastname,
      email: email,
      password: password,
    };
    try {
      return await axios.post(`${API_URL}/auth/register.php`, formData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      //return { error: true, msg: error.response.data.msg };
    }
  };

  const login = async (email, password) => {
    try {
      axios.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] =
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
      const result = await axios.post(`${API_URL}/auth/login.php`, {
        email,
        password,
      });
      if (result.data.result == "success") {
        setAuthState({
          token: result.data.token,
          authenticated: true,
        });

        await AsyncStorage.setItem(TOKEN_KEY, result.data.token);
        axios.defaults.headers.common[
          "Authorization"
        ] = `Bearer ${result.data.token}`;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      //return { error: true, msg: error.response.data.msg };
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const logout = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem(TOKEN_KEY);

    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = null;

    //reset auth state
    setAuthState({
      token: null,
      authenticated: false,
    });
  };
  const useaxiosfetch = async (url, formdata) => {
    axios.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] =
      "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    try {
      return await axios.post(`${API_URL}/${url}`, formdata);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  const value = {
    onRegister: register,
    onLogin: login,
    onLogout: logout,
    useAxios: useaxiosfetch,
    authState,
  };

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};
```

This is my Games.jsx page which throws the error:

```
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useAuth } from "../context/AuthContext";
import GameCard from "../components/GameCard";

const Games = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const { useAxios } = useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getGames = async () => {
      try {
        const formData = {
          filter_location: "all",
          filter_category: "all",
        };
        const response = await useAxios("games/get_all.php", formData);
        setData(response?.data.result);
        
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    };
    getGames();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ScrollView className="p-4 flex-1">
      <Text className="text-lg font-medium">Games in your area</Text>
      {data?.map((game) => (
          <GameCard
            key={game.id}
            id={game.id}
            title={game.title}
          />
        ))}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default Games;
```

This is the error:

```
undefined is not a function
at screens\Games.jsx:null in Games
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:null in renderWithHooks
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:null in updateFunctionComponent
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:null in beginWork
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:null in beginWork$1
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:null in performUnitOfWork
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:null in workLoopSync
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:null in renderRootSync
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:null in performSyncWorkOnRoot
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:null in flushSyncCallbacks
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:null in flushSyncCallbacksOnlyInLegacyMode
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:null in scheduleUpdateOnFiber
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:null in dispatchSetState
at screens\Games.jsx:null in getGames
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:null in asyncGeneratorStep
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:null in _next
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in _allocateCallback$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in _callTimer
- ... 8 more stack frames from framework internals
```

It works fine when using the web. Not sure what is going on, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you figure this one out?